# How can I show/hide textarea values when the user types on the search bar?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search, textarea

I'm sorry for my English in advance, it's not my native language. I'm creating a tool for personal use. It's an **Image Path Generator tool**. It's used to generate a new path for the image filenames uploaded.

This tool needs **2 user inputs:**
**(1)** Upload the image files (can be more than one)
**(2)** Input the new path of the images

[image: user_inputs]

When the images are uploaded and generated, the output will show inside the 2 text areas. **One textarea shows the new path + filenames** of the images while the **second textarea shows the filenames only** of the images.

[image: two-outputs]

I already created a search bar function and it works while the user types but the problem is, **how can I bring back the original textarea values** when the user doesn't type anything inside the search bar?

[image: search_bar]
[image: search_bar2]

***NOTE:** I only created a search function in the **New Path + Image Filename(s)** textarea section.*

---

**Codes:**

```js
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function() 
          {

          
      // THIS IS THE SEARCH BAR FUNCTION
            $('#searchDir').keyup(function()
              {
                var val = $(this).val();
                var lines1 = $('#outputText').val();
                lines1 = lines1.split(/\n/);
                var originalDirect = [];

                for(var o=0; o < lines1.length; o++)
                {
                    // var text0 = lines1[o];
                    originalDirect.push((lines1[o]));
                    console.log(originalDirect);
                }

                    if(val != null)
                    {
                        // $(lines1).hide();

                        var searchDirect = [];

                        for (var a=0; a < lines1.length; a++)
                        {
                            var text = lines1[a];
                            if(text.indexOf(val) != -1)
                              {
                                // $(this).show();
                                searchDirect.push((lines1[a]));
                              }
                        }

                        $('#outputText').val(searchDirect.join('\n'));

                        // $(lines1).each(function()
                        // {
                           //    var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                           //    if(text.indexOf(val) != -1)
                           //    {
                           //      $(this).show();
                           //    }
                        // });
                    }
                    else if(val == null)
                    {
                         $('#outputText').val(originalDirect.join('\n'));
                    }

                   
              });


            $('.output1').hover(function(){
                $('.copy-btn1').addClass('copy-btn-show');
            }, function(){
                $('.copy-btn1').removeClass('copy-btn-show');
            });

            $('.output2').hover(function(){
                $('.copy-btn2').addClass('copy-btn-show');
            }, function(){
                $('.copy-btn2').removeClass('copy-btn-show');
            });


            $('.copy-btn1').click(function()
            {
                $('.copy-btn1').attr('data-content', 'Copied to clipboard!')
                $('.copy-btn1').popover('show');
                var copyText = $('#outputText');
                copyText.select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                copyText.blur();
                setTimeout(function(){ $('.copy-btn1').popover('hide') }, 1000);
            });

            $('.copy-btn2').click(function()
            {
                $('.copy-btn2').attr('data-content', 'Copied to clipboard!')
                $('.copy-btn2').popover('show');
                var copyText = $('#filenameText');
                copyText.select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                copyText.blur();
                setTimeout(function(){ $('.copy-btn2').popover('hide') }, 1000);
            });


            

            
         


          });



        function makeFileList() {
            var input = document.getElementById("filesToUpload");
            var addtext = $('#addText').val();
            //var inputAffix = $('#inputAffix').val();
            var ul = document.getElementById("fileList");
            var outputData = [];
            var fileNames = [];
            var countSrc = 0;
            while (ul.hasChildNodes()) {

                ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                // var p = document.createElement("p");
                // p.innerHTML = addtext + input.files[i].name;
                outputData.push((addtext + input.files[i].name));
                fileNames.push((input.files[i].name));
                countSrc++;
                // ul.appendChild(p);
            }
            if(!ul.hasChildNodes()) {
                // var p = document.createElement("p");
                // p.innerHTML = 'No Files Selected';
                // ul.appendChild(p);
            }



            $('#outputText').val(outputData.join('\n'));
            $('#filenameText').val(fileNames.join('\n'));
            $('.numbSrc').html(countSrc);
        }

        function countImages(changeBGColor)
        {
            var input = document.getElementById("filesToUpload");
            var labelElem = document.getElementById("labelUpload");
            var upCont = document.getElementById("uploadCont");
            // $('#countImg').html(input.files.length + " Images");

            if (input.files.length == 0)
            {
                $('#labelUpload').html(" No Image Uploaded!");
                labelElem.style.background = "red";
                upCont.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 5px 1px red";
                upCont.style.border = "none";
                upCont.style.borderRadius = "8px";
                labelElem.style.color = 'white';
                labelElem.border = "none";
                labelElem.style.fontWeight = '700';
            }
            else if (input.files.length == 1)
            {
                $('#labelUpload').html(input.files.length + " Image Uploaded!");
                labelElem.style.background = changeBGColor;
                upCont.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 5px 1px #097579";
                upCont.style.border = "none";
                upCont.style.borderRadius = "8px";
                labelElem.style.color = 'white';
                labelElem.border = "none";
                labelElem.style.fontWeight = '700';
            }
            else
            {
                $('#labelUpload').html(input.files.length + " Images Uploaded!");
                labelElem.style.background = changeBGColor;
                upCont.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 5px 1px #097579";
                upCont.style.border = "none";
                upCont.style.borderRadius = "8px";
                labelElem.style.color = 'white';
                labelElem.border = "none";
                labelElem.style.fontWeight = '700';
            }

            
        }

    </script>
```

```css
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color:#20629F!important;
   background-color:rgba(204, 230, 255, 0.76) !important;
   /* color:#20629F!important;*/
   /* color:white!important;*/
  /* background-color:rgb(204, 230, 255, 0.07) !important;*/
 /* background: rgb(242,242,242);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(242,242,242,1) 0%, rgba(9,71,121,0.6587009803921569) 0%, rgba(102,231,235,0.7763480392156863) 100%);*/
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
  font-weight: 600;
}

h4
{
 /* color:#061420!important;*/
 /* color:white!important;*/
 color:#093e79 !important;
  text-align: center; 
}

/*SIDE NAV MENU*/
#mySidenav
{
  position: fixed;
  z-index:6 !important;
}

#howToContainer {
  top: 2px;
 /* background-color: #2675BF;*/
  position: absolute;
  left: -615px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
  width: 770px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
 /* border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;*/
}

#howToContainer:hover {
  left: 0px;
  /*background-color: #339CFF;*/
}

#howToContainer .howToTitle
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  right:-0vh;
  font-size: 16px;
  /*background-color: #2675BF;*/
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width:50%;
}

#howToContainer .howToTitle span
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:right;
  color:#2675BF;
}

#howToContainer .howToTitle span img
{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  margin-left:1em;
  background-color:#2675BF;
  border-radius:0px 10px 10px 0;
}

#howToContainer:hover .howToTitle{
  background-color: #339CFF;
}

#howToContainer:hover .howToTitle span
{
  color:white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#howToContainer .howToText
{
  border: 1px solid rgba(51, 156, 255);
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color: white;
  width:600px;
  padding:1em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;

}

#howToContainer .howToText ol li
{
 font-size: 14px;
 color:#20629F!important;
}

#howToContainer:hover .howToText
{
  color:#061420!important;
  font-weight: 400;
  border:1px solid white;
 /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px white;*/
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #2D89DF;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #2D89DF;*/
}

 /*END OF SIDENAV MENU*/

.directoryInput
{
  text-indent:8px;
  font-size:14px !important;
 /* color:#0C253C!important;*/
 color:#20629F!important;
  font-weight: 400;
  height:100%;
}

.directoryInput::placeholder
{
  font-style:italic;
}

/*.directoryInput::focus DOESNT WORK!!!
{
  color:#061420!important;
    font-weight: 400;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #2D89DF;
} */

.form-control:focus 
{
  /*border:2px solid rgb(38, 117, 191) !important;*/
  /*box-shadow: none!important;*/
  border:none!important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #2D89DF !important;
}

.searchBar::placeholder
{
   color:rgba(38, 117, 191, 0.65);
    font-size:13px;
}

.fa-search
{
  color:#2D89DF;
  position: absolute;
  float:right;
  right:1em;
  top:0.5em;
}

/*.form-control:focus .fa-search DOESNT WORK!!!
{
   color:#093579 !important;
}*/

/*Copy Button*/
.copy-btn1, .copy-btn2
{
    border:1px solid rgb(38, 117, 191);
    padding:7px 30px;
    margin-right:6px;
    border-radius:7px 7px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom:none;
    transform: translate3d(0, 28px, -1px);
    color:#2D89DF !important;
    transition:all .3s;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .copy-btn-show{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, -1px);
  /*  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #20629F;*/
    border:1px solid #2D89DF;
    border-bottom:none;
    /*background-color:#2D89DF;*/
    color:#2D89DF !important;
    z-index: -1;
    cursor:pointer;
    user-select: none;
    font-weight:800;
  }

  .copy-btn-show:hover
  {
    background-color:#2D89DF;
    color:white !important;
  }
/*END OF Copy Button*/


#genButton
{
   /*border: 1px solid rgb(19, 59, 96);*/
  /* background-color:white;*/
  background-color:#2D89DF;
  padding:0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  /*color:rgb(19, 59, 96);*/
  color:white!important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:15px;
}

#genButton:hover
{
  /* border: 1px solid rgb(19, 59, 96);*/
   background-color:rgb(19, 59, 96);
   color:white!important;
}

.inputTA
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:3px 20px 0 20px;
}   


.inputTA2
{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:3px 20px 0 20px;
}   


.outputTAstyle, .outputTAstyle2{
border: 1px solid rgba(51, 156, 255);
    border-radius:5px;
    width:800px;
    height:500px;
    font-size:13px !important;
    color:#0C253C!important;
    margin:0 0;
    outline:none;
    padding:15px 15px;
    z-index: 99999;
    transform: translateZ(3px);
    transition: all .3s;
  }

  .outputTAstyle:focus , .outputTAstyle2:focus{
    /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #ffffff;
    border-color:white;*/
    cursor:default!important;
    /*color:#061420!important;*/
    /*border:1px solid white;*/
    color:#061420!important;
    font-weight: 400;
    /*border-color: #2D89DF;*/
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #2D89DF;
    /*font-weight: 500;*/
    /*border-color: #2D89DF;*/
    /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px white;*/
      
  }

/*  .outputTAstyle2[readonly]
  {
    background-color:rgb(229, 243, 255) !important;
  }*/

  ::placeholder{
    color:rgba(38, 117, 191, 0.65);
    font-size:15px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
  }

/*
.footer
{
  color:#0D2740 !important;
  font-weight: 600;
}*/
```

```html
<!-- Programmed by Christine Jane Kudera ¯\_( ͡❛ ͜ʖ͡❛ )_/¯ -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Path Generator</title>

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- for the material icons -->
    

</head>



<body>

<!-- HOW TO USE CONTAINER -->
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
              <a href="#" class="containerStyle" id="howToContainer" title="How to Use" alt="How to Use">
                <div class="howToTitle">
                    <span>How to Use<img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/TIA4R33jmGPPis5KPv/giphy.gif"><!-- <img src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/9Daw0eNNSE0e9WM2lI/source.gif" style="width:40px;height:40px;"> -->
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="howToText">
                        <ol>
                            <li> <b>Upload/Choose the images</b> you wanted to generate a new image path. <i>(Can be more than 1)</i></li>
                            <li> Input the new path inside the <b>Path Input Form</b>.</li>
                            <li> Click the <b>Generate button</b>.</li>
                            <li> The Left Textarea contains the <b>filenames of the images with the path</b> while the Right Textarea contains the <b>filenames only</b>.</li>
                            <li> Copy the new image sources from the Left Textarea.</li>
                        </ol>
                </div>
              </a>

    </div>  

<center>

<h4 style="margin-top:1vh;">Image Path Generator</h4>
    
    <!-- UPLOAD FILES INPUT -->
    <div class="row" style="width:50%;">
        <!-- <small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;float:right;">No. of Images Uploaded:&nbsp;<span id="countImg" style="font-weight: 600;"></span> </small> -->
        <div class="input-group mb-3" id="uploadCont" style="z-index:1 !important;margin-top:0 !important;padding-top:0 !important;">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"  style="font-size:14px;padding:0 1.5em;"><strong>Upload</strong></span>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" onchange="countImages('#2D89DF')" multiple="">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" id="labelUpload" for="filesToUpload" style="text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-weight: 500;color:#20629F!important;padding-left:20px;">Choose Images...</label>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end of row -->
    

    <!-- DIRECTORY INPUT FORM -->
    <div class="row" style="width:50%;">
            <!-- h5><strong>DIRECTORY:</strong></h5> -->
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:0 !important;padding-bottom:0 !important;">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size:14px;padding:0 1.5em;"><strong>Path</strong></span>
                  </div>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control directoryInput" aria-label="directory" name="addText" id="addText" value="images/newImg/2020/08/"/>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn" id="genButton" onclick="makeFileList()">Generate</button>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;"><strong>&nbsp;| e.g. |</strong> images/newImg/2020/08/</small>
    </div> <!-- end of row -->
    
    <ul id="fileList"></ul>

    <div class="inputTA output1">
        <p><strong style="color:#093579;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;line-height: 0;">New Path + Image Filename<small><b>(s)</b></small>:</strong></p>
        <p><small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;"><strong>| e.g. |</strong> images/newImg/2020/08/image1.jpg</small></p>
        <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:1em;margin-top:0.5em;">
            <small style=""><strong>Img src:</strong>&nbsp;<span style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;" class="numbSrc">0</span></small>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:3em;margin-top:0;position: relative;">
            <i class="fa fa-search" style=""></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control searchBar" id="searchDir" style="width:500px;height:30px;border-radius:30px;font-size:13px;" placeholder="Search image here...">
        </div>
        <div class ="copy-holder">
                    <span class = "float-right copy-btn1" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Copied to Clipboard!">Copy</span>
        </div>
        <textarea id="outputText" class="outputTAstyle"  placeholder="New Path + Image Filename(s) here..." readonly></textarea>
    </div>
      
   <div class="inputTA2 output2">
        <p><strong style="color:#093579;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;line-height: 0;">Image Filename<small><b>(s)</b></small> only:</strong></p>
        <p><small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;"><strong>| e.g. |</strong> image1.jpg</small></p>
        <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:1em;margin-top:0.5em;">
            <small style=""><strong>Img src:</strong>&nbsp;<span style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;" class="numbSrc">0</span></small>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:3em;margin-top:0;position: relative;">
            <i class="fa fa-search" style=""></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control searchBar" style="width:500px;height:30px;border-radius:30px;font-size:13px;" placeholder="Search image here...">
        </div>
        <div class ="copy-holder">
                    <span class = "float-right copy-btn2" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Copied to Clipboard!">Copy</span>
        </div>
        <textarea id="filenameText" class="outputTAstyle2"   placeholder="Image Filename(s) only here..." readonly></textarea>
    </div>


</center>   
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is by  declaring variable globally so that it can use in entire code .In below code i have declare two variable globally i.e : `original_datas` & `original_filenames` to store values of file path and file name .

Whenever user upload file we can assign value `outputData` which has entire list of file to these global variable and if the value is **null** of input-box we can use these global variable to assign `value` of textarea. Same you can do for other input-box for searching filename.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$('#searchDir').keyup(function() {
  var lines1;
  var val = $(this).val();
  lines1 = $('#outputText').val();
  lines1 = lines1.split(/\n/);
  var originalDirect = [];
  //check if value is not null
  if ((val != null) && (val != '')) {
    for (var o = 0; o < lines1.length; o++) {
      originalDirect.push((lines1[o]));
    }
    var searchDirect = [];

    for (var a = 0; a < lines1.length; a++) {
      var text = lines1[a];
      if (text.indexOf(val) != -1) {
        // $(this).show();
        searchDirect.push((lines1[a]));
      }
    }
    $('#outputText').val(searchDirect.join('\n'));
  } else if (val == '') {
    console.log("value is null")
    $('#outputText').val(original_datas);//add value to textarea
  }
});

//declare this globally
var original_datas; //for path+image search
var original_filenames;//for file search

function makeFileList() {
  var input = document.getElementById("filesToUpload");
  var addtext = $('#addText').val();
  //var inputAffix = $('#inputAffix').val();
  var ul = document.getElementById("fileList");
  var outputData = [];
  var fileNames = [];
  var countSrc = 0;
  while (ul.hasChildNodes()) {

    ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
    outputData.push((addtext + input.files[i].name));
    fileNames.push((input.files[i].name));
    countSrc++;
  }
  if (!ul.hasChildNodes()) {
  }
 //assign values to use later
  original_datas = outputData.join('\n');
  original_filenames = fileNames.join('\n');
  $('#outputText').val(outputData.join('\n'));
  $('#filenameText').val(fileNames.join('\n'));
  $('.numbSrc').html(countSrc);
}

function countImages(changeBGColor) {
  var input = document.getElementById("filesToUpload");
  var labelElem = document.getElementById("labelUpload");
  var upCont = document.getElementById("uploadCont");
  if (input.files.length == 0) {
    $('#labelUpload').html(" No Image Uploaded!");
    labelElem.style.background = "red";
    upCont.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 5px 1px red";
    upCont.style.border = "none";
    upCont.style.borderRadius = "8px";
    labelElem.style.color = 'white';
    labelElem.border = "none";
    labelElem.style.fontWeight = '700';
  } else if (input.files.length == 1) {
    $('#labelUpload').html(input.files.length + " Image Uploaded!");
    labelElem.style.background = changeBGColor;
    upCont.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 5px 1px #097579";
    upCont.style.border = "none";
    upCont.style.borderRadius = "8px";
    labelElem.style.color = 'white';
    labelElem.border = "none";
    labelElem.style.fontWeight = '700';
  } else {
    $('#labelUpload').html(input.files.length + " Images Uploaded!");
    labelElem.style.background = changeBGColor;
    upCont.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 5px 1px #097579";
    upCont.style.border = "none";
    upCont.style.borderRadius = "8px";
    labelElem.style.color = 'white';
    labelElem.border = "none";
    labelElem.style.fontWeight = '700';
  }


}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #20629F!important;
  background-color: rgba(204, 230, 255, 0.76) !important;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

h4 {
  /* color:#061420!important;*/
  /* color:white!important;*/
  color: #093e79 !important;
  text-align: center;
}


/*SIDE NAV MENU*/

#mySidenav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 6 !important;
}

#howToContainer {
  top: 2px;
  /* background-color: #2675BF;*/
  position: absolute;
  left: -615px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
  width: 770px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  /* border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;*/
}

#howToContainer:hover {
  left: 0px;
  /*background-color: #339CFF;*/
}

#howToContainer .howToTitle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  right: -0vh;
  font-size: 16px;
  /*background-color: #2675BF;*/
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width: 50%;
}

#howToContainer .howToTitle span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
  color: #2675BF;
}

#howToContainer .howToTitle span img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 1em;
  background-color: #2675BF;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0;
}

#howToContainer:hover .howToTitle {
  background-color: #339CFF;
}

#howToContainer:hover .howToTitle span {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#howToContainer .howToText {
  border: 1px solid rgba(51, 156, 255);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 1em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
}

#howToContainer .howToText ol li {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #20629F!important;
}

#howToContainer:hover .howToText {
  color: #061420!important;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid white;
  /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px white;*/
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #2D89DF;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #2D89DF;*/
}


/*END OF SIDENAV MENU*/

.directoryInput {
  text-indent: 8px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  /* color:#0C253C!important;*/
  color: #20629F!important;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 100%;
}

.directoryInput::placeholder {
  font-style: italic;
}


/*.directoryInput::focus DOESNT WORK!!!
    {
      color:#061420!important;
        font-weight: 400;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #2D89DF;
    } */

.form-control:focus {
  /*border:2px solid rgb(38, 117, 191) !important;*/
  /*box-shadow: none!important;*/
  border: none!important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #2D89DF !important;
}

.searchBar::placeholder {
  color: rgba(38, 117, 191, 0.65);
  font-size: 13px;
}

.fa-search {
  color: #2D89DF;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  right: 1em;
  top: 0.5em;
}


/*.form-control:focus .fa-search DOESNT WORK!!!
    {
       color:#093579 !important;
    }*/


/*Copy Button*/

.copy-btn1,
.copy-btn2 {
  border: 1px solid rgb(38, 117, 191);
  padding: 7px 30px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform: translate3d(0, 28px, -1px);
  color: #2D89DF !important;
  transition: all .3s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.copy-btn-show {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0px, -1px);
  /*  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #20629F;*/
  border: 1px solid #2D89DF;
  border-bottom: none;
  /*background-color:#2D89DF;*/
  color: #2D89DF !important;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.copy-btn-show:hover {
  background-color: #2D89DF;
  color: white !important;
}


/*END OF Copy Button*/

#genButton {
  /*border: 1px solid rgb(19, 59, 96);*/
  /* background-color:white;*/
  background-color: #2D89DF;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  /*color:rgb(19, 59, 96);*/
  color: white!important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#genButton:hover {
  /* border: 1px solid rgb(19, 59, 96);*/
  background-color: rgb(19, 59, 96);
  color: white!important;
}

.inputTA {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 20px 0 20px;
}

.inputTA2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px 20px 0 20px;
}

.outputTAstyle,
.outputTAstyle2 {
  border: 1px solid rgba(51, 156, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  color: #0C253C!important;
  margin: 0 0;
  outline: none;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  z-index: 99999;
  transform: translateZ(3px);
  transition: all .3s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>

  <!-- HOW TO USE CONTAINER -->
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="#" class="containerStyle" id="howToContainer" title="How to Use" alt="How to Use">
      <div class="howToTitle">
        <span>How to Use<img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/TIA4R33jmGPPis5KPv/giphy.gif"><!-- <img src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/9Daw0eNNSE0e9WM2lI/source.gif" style="width:40px;height:40px;"> -->
                        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="howToText">
        <ol>
          <li> <b>Upload/Choose the images</b> you wanted to generate a new image path. <i>(Can be more than 1)</i></li>
          <li> Input the new path inside the <b>Path Input Form</b>.</li>
          <li> Click the <b>Generate button</b>.</li>
          <li> The Left Textarea contains the <b>filenames of the images with the path</b> while the Right Textarea contains the <b>filenames only</b>.</li>
          <li> Copy the new image sources from the Left Textarea.</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>

  <center>

    <h4 style="margin-top:1vh;">Image Path Generator</h4>

    <!-- UPLOAD FILES INPUT -->
    <div class="row" style="width:50%;">
      <!-- <small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;float:right;">No. of Images Uploaded:&nbsp;<span id="countImg" style="font-weight: 600;"></span> </small> -->
      <div class="input-group mb-3" id="uploadCont" style="z-index:1 !important;margin-top:0 !important;padding-top:0 !important;">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size:14px;padding:0 1.5em;"><strong>Upload</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-file">
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" onchange="countImages('#2D89DF')" multiple="">
          <label class="custom-file-label" id="labelUpload" for="filesToUpload" style="text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-weight: 500;color:#20629F!important;padding-left:20px;">Choose Images...</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of row -->


    <!-- DIRECTORY INPUT FORM -->
    <div class="row" style="width:50%;">
      <!-- h5><strong>DIRECTORY:</strong></h5> -->
      <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:0 !important;padding-bottom:0 !important;">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size:14px;padding:0 1.5em;"><strong>Path</strong></span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control directoryInput" aria-label="directory" name="addText" id="addText" value="images/newImg/2020/08/" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn" id="genButton" onclick="makeFileList()">Generate</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;"><strong>&nbsp;| e.g. |</strong> images/newImg/2020/08/</small>
    </div>
    <!-- end of row -->

    <ul id="fileList"></ul>

    <div class="inputTA output1">
      <p><strong style="color:#093579;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;line-height: 0;">New Path + Image Filename<small><b>(s)</b></small>:</strong></p>
      <p><small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;"><strong>| e.g. |</strong> images/newImg/2020/08/image1.jpg</small></p>
      <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:1em;margin-top:0.5em;">
        <small style=""><strong>Img src:</strong>&nbsp;<span style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;" class="numbSrc">0</span></small>
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:3em;margin-top:0;position: relative;">
        <i class="fa fa-search" style=""></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control searchBar" id="searchDir" style="width:500px;height:30px;border-radius:30px;font-size:13px;" placeholder="Search image here...">
      </div>
      <div class="copy-holder">
        <span class="float-right copy-btn1" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Copied to Clipboard!">Copy</span>
      </div>
      <textarea id="outputText" class="outputTAstyle" placeholder="New Path + Image Filename(s) here..." readonly></textarea>
      <!--<div class="outputTAstyle" id="outputText" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" placeholder="New Path + Image Filename(s) here..." readonly></div>-->
    </div>

    <div class="inputTA2 output2">
      <p><strong style="color:#093579;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;line-height: 0;">Image Filename<small><b>(s)</b></small> only:</strong></p>
      <p><small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;"><strong>| e.g. |</strong> image1.jpg</small></p>
      <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:1em;margin-top:0.5em;">
        <small style=""><strong>Img src:</strong>&nbsp;<span style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;" class="numbSrc">0</span></small>
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:3em;margin-top:0;position: relative;">
        <i class="fa fa-search" style=""></i>
        <input type="text" class="form-control searchBar" style="width:500px;height:30px;border-radius:30px;font-size:13px;" placeholder="Search image here...">
      </div>
      <div class="copy-holder">
        <span class="float-right copy-btn2" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Copied to Clipboard!">Copy</span>
      </div>
      <textarea id="filenameText" class="outputTAstyle2" placeholder="Image Filename(s) only here..." readonly></textarea>
    </div>


  </center>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already got it after many tries but I think mine was more complicated. I like yours better. It's neat and simple.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is you need to store the original names to compare old versus new names. It looks like your functionality is on the right path but implement somewhere before you store the filename to also store to another area of the old name. Make sense?

Comment: yeah. I thought of that too but I'm kinda new to jquery and I don't know how or where to implement that. :(

Answer (score 0):

I finally know how to implement it after many tries but I think I made it more complicated than it has to be.

Like the previous answers given, I tried to store the **original values of the 2 textareas** in **2 arrays** and declaring it globally so that I can call it again everytime the user does not type in the search bar.

This works everytime the user clicks on the Generate button. **The original values will be stored in arrays everytime it's clicked**. I also made sure to **declare the arrays to 0(zero)** every time the Generate button is clicked so that the previous values will be gone and new values will be stored instead.

I also added the same functions to the **2nd textare, the Filenames only** section.

```js
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function() 
          {
            
              //Store the Original Values of the 2 Text Areas
            var originalDirect = [];
            var originalFile = [];
            var origNum1 = 0;
            var origNum2 = 0;

            //Save the Original Values of the 2 Text Areas everytime the Generate Button is clicked
            $('#genButton').click(function()
            {
                originalDirect.length = 0;
                originalFile.length = 0;
                origNum1 = 0;
                origNum2 = 0;


                var lines0 = $('#outputText').val();
                var lines0b = $('#filenameText').val();
                lines0 = lines0.split(/\n/);
                lines0b = lines0b.split(/\n/);

                for(var o=0; o < lines0.length; o++)
                {
                    originalDirect.push((lines0[o]));
                    origNum1++;
                }

                for(var p=0; p < lines0b.length; p++)
                {
                    originalFile.push((lines0b[p]));
                    origNum2++;
                }


            });

            //SEARCH BAR FUNCTION in PATH + FILENAME TEXTAREA
            $('#searchDir').keyup(function()
              {
                var val = $(this).val();
                var lines1 = $('#outputText').val();
                lines1 = lines1.split(/\n/);
                var countDir = 0;
            
                    if(val != '')
                    {
                        var searchDirect = [];

                        for (var a=0; a < lines1.length; a++)
                        {
                            var text = lines1[a];
                            if(text.indexOf(val) != -1)
                              {
                                searchDirect.push((lines1[a]));
                                countDir++;
                              }
                        }

                        $('#outputText').val(searchDirect.join('\n'));
                        $('.numbSrc1').html(countDir);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         $('#outputText').val(originalDirect.join('\n'));
                         $('.numbSrc1').html(origNum1);
                    }

                   
              });

            //SEARCH BAR FUNCTION in FILENAME ONLY TEXTAREA
            $('#searchFil').keyup(function()
              {
                var val2 = $(this).val();
                var lines1b = $('#filenameText').val();
                lines1b = lines1b.split(/\n/);
                var countDir2 = 0;
            
                    if(val2 != '')
                    {
                        var searchDirect2 = [];

                        for (var a=0; a < lines1b.length; a++)
                        {
                            var text2 = lines1b[a];
                            if(text2.indexOf(val2) != -1)
                              {
                                searchDirect2.push((lines1b[a]));
                                countDir2++;
                              }
                        }

                        $('#filenameText').val(searchDirect2.join('\n'));
                        $('.numbSrc2').html(countDir2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         $('#filenameText').val(originalFile.join('\n'));
                         $('.numbSrc2').html(origNum2);
                    }

                   
              });

          
     

            $('.output1').hover(function(){
                $('.copy-btn1').addClass('copy-btn-show');
            }, function(){
                $('.copy-btn1').removeClass('copy-btn-show');
            });

            $('.output2').hover(function(){
                $('.copy-btn2').addClass('copy-btn-show');
            }, function(){
                $('.copy-btn2').removeClass('copy-btn-show');
            });


            $('.copy-btn1').click(function()
            {
                $('.copy-btn1').attr('data-content', 'Copied to clipboard!')
                $('.copy-btn1').popover('show');
                var copyText = $('#outputText');
                copyText.select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                copyText.blur();
                setTimeout(function(){ $('.copy-btn1').popover('hide') }, 1000);
            });

            $('.copy-btn2').click(function()
            {
                $('.copy-btn2').attr('data-content', 'Copied to clipboard!')
                $('.copy-btn2').popover('show');
                var copyText = $('#filenameText');
                copyText.select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                copyText.blur();
                setTimeout(function(){ $('.copy-btn2').popover('hide') }, 1000);
            });


            

            
         


          });



        function makeFileList() {
            var input = document.getElementById("filesToUpload");
            var addtext = $('#addText').val();
            //var inputAffix = $('#inputAffix').val();
            var ul = document.getElementById("fileList");
            var outputData = [];
            var fileNames = [];
            var countSrc = 0;
            while (ul.hasChildNodes()) {

                ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
                // var p = document.createElement("p");
                // p.innerHTML = addtext + input.files[i].name;
                outputData.push((addtext + input.files[i].name));
                fileNames.push((input.files[i].name));
                countSrc++;
                // ul.appendChild(p);
            }
            if(!ul.hasChildNodes()) {
                // var p = document.createElement("p");
                // p.innerHTML = 'No Files Selected';
                // ul.appendChild(p);
            }



            $('#outputText').val(outputData.join('\n'));
            $('#filenameText').val(fileNames.join('\n'));
            $('.numbSrc1').html(countSrc);
            $('.numbSrc2').html(countSrc);

        }

        function countImages(changeBGColor)
        {
            var input = document.getElementById("filesToUpload");
            var labelElem = document.getElementById("labelUpload");
            var upCont = document.getElementById("uploadCont");
            // $('#countImg').html(input.files.length + " Images");

            if (input.files.length == 0)
            {
                $('#labelUpload').html(" No Image Uploaded!");
                labelElem.style.background = "red";
                upCont.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 5px 1px red";
                upCont.style.border = "none";
                upCont.style.borderRadius = "8px";
                labelElem.style.color = 'white';
                labelElem.border = "none";
                labelElem.style.fontWeight = '700';
            }
            else if (input.files.length == 1)
            {
                $('#labelUpload').html(input.files.length + " Image Uploaded!");
                labelElem.style.background = changeBGColor;
                upCont.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 5px 1px #097579";
                upCont.style.border = "none";
                upCont.style.borderRadius = "8px";
                labelElem.style.color = 'white';
                labelElem.border = "none";
                labelElem.style.fontWeight = '700';
            }
            else
            {
                $('#labelUpload').html(input.files.length + " Images Uploaded!");
                labelElem.style.background = changeBGColor;
                upCont.style.boxShadow = "1px 1px 5px 1px #097579";
                upCont.style.border = "none";
                upCont.style.borderRadius = "8px";
                labelElem.style.color = 'white';
                labelElem.border = "none";
                labelElem.style.fontWeight = '700';
            }

            
        }

    </script>
```

```css
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color:#20629F!important;
   background-color:rgba(204, 230, 255, 0.76) !important;
   /* color:#20629F!important;*/
   /* color:white!important;*/
  /* background-color:rgb(204, 230, 255, 0.07) !important;*/
 /* background: rgb(242,242,242);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(242,242,242,1) 0%, rgba(9,71,121,0.6587009803921569) 0%, rgba(102,231,235,0.7763480392156863) 100%);*/
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
{
  font-weight: 600;
}

h4
{
 /* color:#061420!important;*/
 /* color:white!important;*/
 color:#093e79 !important;
  text-align: center; 
}

/*SIDE NAV MENU*/
#mySidenav
{
  position: fixed;
  z-index:6 !important;
}

#howToContainer {
  top: 2px;
 /* background-color: #2675BF;*/
  position: absolute;
  left: -615px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 3px 15px 3px 15px;
  width: 770px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
 /* border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;*/
}

#howToContainer:hover {
  left: 0px;
  /*background-color: #339CFF;*/
}

#howToContainer .howToTitle
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  right:-0vh;
  font-size: 16px;
  /*background-color: #2675BF;*/
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width:50%;
}

#howToContainer .howToTitle span
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float:right;
  color:#2675BF;
}

#howToContainer .howToTitle span img
{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  margin-left:1em;
  background-color:#2675BF;
  border-radius:0px 10px 10px 0;
}

#howToContainer:hover .howToTitle{
  background-color: #339CFF;
}

#howToContainer:hover .howToTitle span
{
  color:white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#howToContainer .howToText
{
  border: 1px solid rgba(51, 156, 255);
  border-radius:10px;
  background-color: white;
  width:600px;
  padding:1em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;

}

#howToContainer .howToText ol li
{
 font-size: 14px;
 color:#20629F!important;
}

#howToContainer:hover .howToText
{
  color:#061420!important;
  font-weight: 400;
  border:1px solid white;
 /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px white;*/
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #2D89DF;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #2D89DF;*/
}

 /*END OF SIDENAV MENU*/

.directoryInput
{
  text-indent:8px;
  font-size:14px !important;
 /* color:#0C253C!important;*/
 color:#20629F!important;
  font-weight: 400;
  height:100%;
}

.directoryInput::placeholder
{
  font-style:italic;
}

/*.directoryInput::focus DOESNT WORK!!!
{
  color:#061420!important;
    font-weight: 400;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #2D89DF;
} */

.form-control:focus 
{
  /*border:2px solid rgb(38, 117, 191) !important;*/
  /*box-shadow: none!important;*/
  border:none!important;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #2D89DF !important;
}

.searchBar::placeholder
{
   color:rgba(38, 117, 191, 0.65);
    font-size:13px;
}

.fa-search
{
  color:#2D89DF;
  position: absolute;
  float:right;
  right:1em;
  top:0.5em;
}

/*.form-control:focus .fa-search DOESNT WORK!!!
{
   color:#093579 !important;
}*/

/*Copy Button*/
.copy-btn1, .copy-btn2
{
    border:1px solid rgb(38, 117, 191);
    padding:7px 30px;
    margin-right:6px;
    border-radius:7px 7px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom:none;
    transform: translate3d(0, 28px, -1px);
    color:#2D89DF !important;
    transition:all .3s;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .copy-btn-show{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0px, -1px);
  /*  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #20629F;*/
    border:1px solid #2D89DF;
    border-bottom:none;
    /*background-color:#2D89DF;*/
    color:#2D89DF !important;
    z-index: -1;
    cursor:pointer;
    user-select: none;
    font-weight:800;
  }

  .copy-btn-show:hover
  {
    background-color:#2D89DF;
    color:white !important;
  }
/*END OF Copy Button*/


#genButton
{
   /*border: 1px solid rgb(19, 59, 96);*/
  /* background-color:white;*/
  background-color:#2D89DF;
  padding:0.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  /*color:rgb(19, 59, 96);*/
  color:white!important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:15px;
}

#genButton:hover
{
  /* border: 1px solid rgb(19, 59, 96);*/
   background-color:rgb(19, 59, 96);
   color:white!important;
}

.inputTA
{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:3px 20px 0 20px;
}   


.inputTA2
{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:3px 20px 0 20px;
}   


.outputTAstyle, .outputTAstyle2{
border: 1px solid rgba(51, 156, 255);
    border-radius:5px;
    width:800px;
    height:500px;
    font-size:13px !important;
    color:#0C253C!important;
    margin:0 0;
    outline:none;
    padding:15px 15px;
    z-index: 99999;
    transform: translateZ(3px);
    transition: all .3s;
  }

  .outputTAstyle:focus , .outputTAstyle2:focus{
    /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #ffffff;
    border-color:white;*/
    cursor:default!important;
    /*color:#061420!important;*/
    /*border:1px solid white;*/
    color:#061420!important;
    font-weight: 400;
    /*border-color: #2D89DF;*/
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px #2D89DF;
    /*font-weight: 500;*/
    /*border-color: #2D89DF;*/
    /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px white;*/
      
  }

/*  .outputTAstyle2[readonly]
  {
    background-color:rgb(229, 243, 255) !important;
  }*/

  ::placeholder{
    color:rgba(38, 117, 191, 0.65);
    font-size:15px;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
  }

/*
.footer
{
  color:#0D2740 !important;
  font-weight: 600;
}*/
```

```html
<!-- Programmed by Christine Jane Kudera ¯\_( ͡❛ ͜ʖ͡❛ )_/¯ -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Path Generator</title>

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- for the material icons -->
    

</head>



<body>

<!-- HOW TO USE CONTAINER -->
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
              <a href="#" class="containerStyle" id="howToContainer" title="How to Use" alt="How to Use">
                <div class="howToTitle">
                    <span>How to Use<img src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/TIA4R33jmGPPis5KPv/giphy.gif"><!-- <img src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/9Daw0eNNSE0e9WM2lI/source.gif" style="width:40px;height:40px;"> -->
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="howToText">
                        <ol>
                            <li> <b>Upload/Choose the images</b> you wanted to generate a new image path. <i>(Can be more than 1)</i></li>
                            <li> Input the new path inside the <b>Path Input Form</b>.</li>
                            <li> Click the <b>Generate button</b>.</li>
                            <li> The Left Textarea contains the <b>filenames of the images with the path</b> while the Right Textarea contains the <b>filenames only</b>.</li>
                            <li> Copy the new image sources from the Left Textarea.</li>
                        </ol>
                </div>
              </a>

    </div>  

<center>

<h4 style="margin-top:1vh;">Image Path Generator</h4>
    
    <!-- UPLOAD FILES INPUT -->
    <div class="row" style="width:50%;">
        <!-- <small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;float:right;">No. of Images Uploaded:&nbsp;<span id="countImg" style="font-weight: 600;"></span> </small> -->
        <div class="input-group mb-3" id="uploadCont" style="z-index:1 !important;margin-top:0 !important;padding-top:0 !important;">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text"  style="font-size:14px;padding:0 1.5em;"><strong>Upload</strong></span>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" onchange="countImages('#2D89DF')" multiple="">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" id="labelUpload" for="filesToUpload" style="text-align:left;font-size:16px;font-weight: 500;color:#20629F!important;padding-left:20px;">Choose Images...</label>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end of row -->
    

    <!-- DIRECTORY INPUT FORM -->
    <div class="row" style="width:50%;">
            <!-- h5><strong>DIRECTORY:</strong></h5> -->
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom:0 !important;padding-bottom:0 !important;">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" style="font-size:14px;padding:0 1.5em;"><strong>Path</strong></span>
                  </div>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control directoryInput" aria-label="directory" name="addText" id="addText" value="images/newImg/2020/08/"/>
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn" id="genButton" onclick="makeFileList()">Generate</button>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;"><strong>&nbsp;| e.g. |</strong> images/newImg/2020/08/</small>
    </div> <!-- end of row -->
    
    <ul id="fileList"></ul>

    <div class="inputTA output1">
        <p><strong style="color:#093579;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;line-height: 0;">New Path + Image Filename<small><b>(s)</b></small>:</strong></p>
        <p><small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;"><strong>| e.g. |</strong> images/newImg/2020/08/image1.jpg</small></p>
        <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:1em;margin-top:0.5em;">
            <small style=""><strong>Img src:</strong>&nbsp;<span style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;" class="numbSrc1">0</span></small>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:3em;margin-top:0;position: relative;">
            <i class="fa fa-search" style=""></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control searchBar" id="searchDir" style="width:500px;height:30px;border-radius:30px;font-size:13px;" placeholder="Search image here...">
        </div>
        <div class ="copy-holder">
                    <span class = "float-right copy-btn1" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Copied to Clipboard!">Copy</span>
        </div>
        <textarea id="outputText" class="outputTAstyle"  placeholder="New Path + Image Filename(s) here..." readonly></textarea>
    </div>
      
   <div class="inputTA2 output2">
        <p><strong style="color:#093579;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;line-height: 0;">Image Filename<small><b>(s)</b></small> only:</strong></p>
        <p><small style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom:0;"><strong>| e.g. |</strong> image1.jpg</small></p>
        <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:1em;margin-top:0.5em;">
            <small style=""><strong>Img src:</strong>&nbsp;<span style="margin-top:0;padding-top:0;line-height: 0;" class="numbSrc2">0</span></small>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;float:left;margin-left:3em;margin-top:0;position: relative;">
            <i class="fa fa-search" style=""></i>
            <input type="text" class="form-control searchBar" id="searchFil" style="width:500px;height:30px;border-radius:30px;font-size:13px;" placeholder="Search image here...">
        </div>
        <div class ="copy-holder">
                    <span class = "float-right copy-btn2" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Copied to Clipboard!">Copy</span>
        </div>
        <textarea id="filenameText" class="outputTAstyle2"   placeholder="Image Filename(s) only here..." readonly></textarea>
    </div>


</center>   
</body>

</html>
```